# Java service - webmethods

Tags: java, webmethods

```
package Folder.Service;

import com.wm.data.*;
import com.wm.util.Values;
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.Service;
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException;

public final class new_javaService_SVC
{

public static final void new_javaService(IData pipeline)
        throws ServiceException {

    // pipeline
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
    String  input1 = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "input1" );
    String  input2 = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "input2" );
    pipelineCursor.destroy();

    String output1 = "hello back, you gave me " + input1 +" and " + input2;

    // pipeline
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor_1 = pipeline.getCursor();
    IDataUtil.put( pipelineCursor_1, "output1", output1 );
    pipelineCursor_1.destroy();
} }
```

I am getting error whenever I run any java service. Error is: 
**Folder.Service is already defined in this compilation unit
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.Service;**

Can anyone please help.

Comment: what is your version?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you did that (or something very similar)

[image]

If you rename `Service` to `Service2` your problem will be solved.

Tried in version 9.8.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot.. I resolved it.. But in a different way. Just created a new folder for java service and placed it. Previously I was having it like what you specified.